# How to run a jar file in javascript and have it return a json

Tags: javascript, json, jar

I have a jar file that returns a json. How can I run it and take the output through javascript?

Comment: be more precise (read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Node.js is server side Js whereas pure js is executed from browser so it may depend on the context. However, you should take a look at java applets although they might not be used nowadays as they should be replaced by JS Frameworks or libraries.

Answer (score 0):

There is a no browser side java compiler i guess, so you must use javascript on the backend side, i suggest use `nodejs`

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('java -jar /file/to/path.jar',(error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
        console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
    }
});
```